# SSH autologin works sporadically

Tags: ssh, puppet, automation, security

I am installing 20 servers.

On each, with a specific user I created a dsa key.

I did `cat key.pub` from each server onto `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the first server

I verified all servers can log in without password to the first server.

Using puppet, I copied the `.ssh/authorized_key` from the first server to all the other servers.

Permissions are the same, 600

I can't log in automatically; it still works from the servers to the first - but not to any other. I log in as the user, ssh to the other servers - and it asks me for password.

I restarted sshd service, but to no avail.
/etc/ssh/sshd_config is the same on the first server and all the others.

This is RHEL6.

Any ideas? Did I do something wrong?

This is the puppet file; it works now -- i had the root as 775

```
file {"/home/user":
    owner   => user,
    group   => user,
    ensure  => directory,
    mode    => 755,
}

file {"/home/user/.ssh":
    owner   => user,
    group   => user,
    ensure  => directory,
    mode    => 700,
}

file {"/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys":
    owner   => user,
    group   => user,
    ensure  => file,
    mode    => 600,
    source => "puppet://puppet/files/user_sshkeys.txt";
}
```

Comment: What do the logs say on the servers where you can't log in? Is the authorized_key file owned by the right owner? Are the permissions on the .ssh **directory** correct as well as those on the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions of the `~/.ssh` directory should be `700`. The permissions of the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file should be `600`. You probably want to limit write permission on the user's home directory to the user.

```
chmod go-w ~/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Instead of using `cat`, try the `ssh-copy-id` command, as it takes care of these permissions.

Can you show us what your Puppet file directives look like? This can probably be corrected there.

Comment: added the relevant puppet manifest to the original question. It works now! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to setup is called "Host Based Authentication". Do web search for this and you will find what you need. It's an advanced SSH topic, that is easy to do, once you have done it.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet (as I write this, version 3.1.1) has a type called `ssh_authorized_key`.
Using this you can simply push your key out to your machine(s) and it will take care of permissions and such for you.

Here is what I have in my config:

```
ssh_authorized_key { 'root pub key':
    ensure  => present,
    key     => "yourkeyhere",
    name    => "name@server",
    user    => "user",
    type    => "ssh-rsa",
```

You can view the relevant documentation [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/type.html#sshauthorizedkey).

Otherwise there are modules that have been written by others that do much the same thing but give some additional options since there are a few limitations with what the `ssh_authorized_key` type does.